# Coronation in England and USA

Tags: riddle, knowledge

***WHO AM I?***

- I am from England.
- I have been crowned five times in my country.
- The father of my namesake in USA was crowned twice in that country.

Comment: Does it possibly start with rot13(pu..)? I have an idea but not sure

Comment: @Prim3numbah Exactly! I think you have the answer :)

Comment: The thing is, I'm still not sure if my answer is correct. I'll think some more!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Sure. Even with the correct starting letters there may be multiple options. I think that's what is holding you back.

Comment: Yes. The numbers add up exactly. But they represent two complete different things, that's what's making me question my answer.

Comment: @Prim3numbah I'm pretty sure you have the right answer from what you have said. It's a riddle. So it's completely possible that they are completely different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **Chelsea** (football club)

I *have been crowned* five times in my country (England)

> Chelsea have **won** the premier league title exactly 5 times. Notice the  "have been crowned" implying that Chelsea can be crowned more times.

The father of my namesake in USA *was crowned* twice in that country.

> The father of the namesake Chelsea (**Chelsea** Clinton) in USA refers to Bill Clinton who **won** the election and became president exactly 2 times. Notice the "was crowned" implying he can't be crowned again.

Comment: I knew you had the answer :) Nice job!

Comment: This whole time I was trying to find an alternative answer that had the exact same method of coronation, but no other answer fitted like this one! Thanks :)